# Series representation of a function. Generating the series formula.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

in general say the question is to find the series representation of $ arctan(3x)$

the solution is the $\int  \sum  (-1)^n * (3x)^{2n}=$

$$ \sum (-1)^n * 3x^{2n+1}/(2n+1) $$

but my confusion is why i can't go from $\int  \sum (-1)^n * (3)^{2n}(x)^{2n}=$

$$\sum(-1)^n * 3^{2n}x^{2n+1}/(2n+1) $$

i'm not sure if this is obvious or not but regardless i don't understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\arctan(x)=\int\sum(-1)^n(x)^{2n}dx$$
This means that
$$\arctan(3x)=\int\sum(-1)^n(3x)^{2n}\boxed{d(3x)}\\
\implies \arctan(3x)=\sum(-1)^n\dfrac{(3x)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$